# Automatically insert line break between letters when I hit ENTER at end of full text with only Korean

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a error with vscode. When I hit ENTER at end of full text, automatically insert line break between letters. This error appear when I type with only Korean, not with English. Please let me know.

- Before hit ENTER
  [image: Before hit ENTER]
- After hit ENTER
  [image: After hit ENTER]

Comment: what OS you are on? perhaps related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3550)?

Comment: I think it's a bug (maybe in the Electron/Chromium). You'd better go to VS Code issue page : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: I work on Mac OS. Thanks. But I think It's not about encoding problem. Because this problem doesn't appear on others computer.